# Webpage reloading on entering correct values

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I've ran into an weird problem. I have created a login page which send data to a PHP page which return some response code like `"00000"` for ok `"404"` for not found etc. I have tested my server with Postman tool and found server is working perfectly fine. When my html send data to server server responds with response code. If the response code comes wrong html alert's it. *However if I enter correct credentials and when server respond with success , My login page reloads for no reason.*
Here's my javascript

```
function validatelog(){
var user_email_log=document.getElementById("user_email_log").value;
var user_pass_log=document.getElementById("user_pass_log").value;
if (user_email_log&&user_pass_log!=null)
{
            var hr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            var url = "../logic/login.php";
            var vars = 
"user_email_log="+user_email_log+"&user_pass_log="+user_pass_log;
            hr.open("POST", url, true);
            hr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-
urlencoded");
            hr.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(hr.readyState == 4 && hr.status == 200) {
                var saman = hr.responseText.trim();
                if(saman=="00000"){
                   alert(saman);
                }else if (saman == "404"){
                    alert("Failed with 404");
                }

                else{
                    alert(saman);
                }
                }
            }
            hr.send(vars);
        }
    }
```

And my html looks like this

```
<input id="user_email_log"/>
 <input id="user_pass_log"/>
 <button onclick="validatelog();">Log in</button>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `type="button"` to the button:

```
<button type="button" onclick="validatelog();">Log in</button>
```

When it is not specified, it is the same as `type="submit"`, and this will cause your page to reload.

Comment: Don't worry, it happens ^-^

Answer (score 0):

if you use jquery you could do this.

```
$(document).on('click', 'button', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $.get('url')
})
```

I think the page is reloading because that is the default behavior.